# How to read and download files from SharePoint's shareable link via using C# in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sharepoint, download, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application where I need to read and download the files from a SharePoint shareable link. Link can either be a folder, file or zip file link.

Please let me know how I can achieve this in my .net core application 3.1 and if we have to use any Microsoft or other external APIs then where I need to register and get the details for API request.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**First Choice:**

You can refer this official doc to add GraphServiceClient in your webapp.

[**Build ASP.NET Core MVC apps with Microsoft Graph**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet-core)

[Then you can download file via SDK.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request)

Second Choice:

You can get `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` via Microsoft Graph Api, then you can use HttpClient to request this url.

[Download Sharepoint File using Microsoft Graph API](https://blog.josephvelliah.com/download-sharepoint-file-using-microsoft-graph-api)

[image]